# How to pass more than one php arrays to python script using json

Tags: php, python, json

I am new to json and I am facing a problem in sending more than one 2D array to python script from php script for calculation. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array-of-arrays and encode that?

```
$meta_arr = array(
   'array1' => $array_number_one,
   'array2' => $array_number_two
);
echo json_encode($meta_arr);
```

Comment: your answer perfectly works for command prompt but when I execute it on browser it gives null output.Do u knw why is dat?